# Fortran returns NaN, calculate pi

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I created several programs in different languages to calculate pi using trapezoidal sums ([C, Perl, and Python similar loops different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835822/c-perl-and-python-similar-loops-different-results)) and now I am trying to write one in Fortran. I don't know anything about the language and I wrote this:

```
program cpi
double precision n, val, pi
integer i, num
n = 1000
num = 1000
val = 0
do i = 1, num
  val = val + ((1 - (i ** 2)) ** 0.5)
end do
pi = (2 / n)*(1 + (2 * val))
print *, pi
end program cpi
```

It returns `NaN` when I compile it with `gfortran` and run it. What does this mean and how can I change it to make it work? The C program I want to compare it to is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double n = 1000, a, h = 0, t, val, pi;
int main(void) 
{
    for(a = 1; a < n; ++a) {
        t = a/n;
        val = pow(1.0-(t*t), 0.5);
        h+=val;
    }
    h = h*2.0;
    pi = (2.0/n)*(1.0+h);
    printf("%.20f\n", pi);
    return 0;
}
```

Any input on fixing the Fortran program would be very nice.

Comment: I must admit that I wondered "wt*?" when I saw four languages in the tags. :)
While there are some connection, the question is still about fortran so please remove python, c and perl.

Comment: @klutt I fixed the question. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: The other versions are helpful for showing what it is supposed to be compared to.

Comment: `((1 - (i ** 2)) ** 0.5)` attempts the root of a negative number.  I suspect you want some sort of `t` rather than `i`.

Comment: Thanks, that is a simple and obvious mistake. It should be i / n instead of i in that spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @chux, the program works now:

```
program cpi
double precision n, val, pi
integer i, num
n = 1000
num = 1000
val = 0
do i = 1, num
  val = val + ((1 - ((i / n) ** 2)) ** 0.5)
end do
pi = (2 / n)*(1 + (2 * val))
print *, pi
end program cpi
```

Comment: For some value of "works". I suggest you learn why in Fortran  ((1 - ((i / n) ** 2)) ** 0.5) is evaluated in "single precision", and then I suggest you learn about the Fortran kind mechanism.